# unity3d facebook Android goes to graph api v2.0 and v1.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Unity3d 4.5.2 and Facecook-unity-sdk 5.1
My app is created after April 30, so it default to Facebook Graph API v2.0

My problem is: 
On some Android devices, player see v1.0 login dialog and other see v2.0 login dialog.

My app is asking for permissions "email,publish_action". 
On v2, it works fine. 
On older Android devices, it goes to V1 and login fails without much error details. If I change permissions to "email" only, then it work on older device as well.

Is there a way to force all clients to go to V2.0 ? It appears facebook unity sdk 5.1 is midway between v1.0 and v2.0? Does my app need to support both?

Comment: For the v1 versions of the login dialog, do you have any more info? For example are they running older version of the Facebook app? Also, our v6 SDK is in beta right now if you want to take a shot at that: First off I'd suggest trying our 6.0 SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads, it is down in the 'BETA' section at the bottom.

Comment: All android devices are using latest fb app version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else stuck at same problem. This appears to be the problem with Facebook unity sdk. Facebook announced the switch to V2 in end of April, but have not released new unity-sdk till August. I've upgraded to Facebook unity sdk 6.0 which has resolved the issue. Now all requests go to V2.